# Selenium : Unable to inspect element on datepicker from chrome/firefox

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have a DatePicker on a page. When I click on it Datepicker comes up. but am unable to inspect any date on the datepicker.

Please find attached HTML code below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<body class="toolbar-tray-open toolbar-horizontal toolbar-fixed toolbar- 
loading">
<div class="form-item__field js-form-item form-item js-form-type-date form- 
item-changed js-form-item-changed">
<input type="date" data-drupal-selector="edit-changed" data-drupal-date- 
format="Y-m-d" id="edit-changed" name="changed" value="" size="30" 
class="form-date form-item__element--date form-item__element" />
</body>
</html>
```

Copy above code and save it as datePicker.html and then open in any browser.
Click on DatePicker field and try to inspect

**Aim:**
Should be able to inspect element and select date using date picker in selenium java
(or)
Should be able to verify date picker is displayed/present using selenium java

**Note:**
Am able to pass data directly to the date box. But my aim is to use the date picker

**Screenshot**
[image]

**Link**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<body class="toolbar-tray-open toolbar-horizontal toolbar-fixed toolbar-loading">
<div class="form-item__field js-form-item form-item js-form-type-date form-item-changed js-form-item-changed">
<input type="date" data-drupal-selector="edit-changed" data-drupal-date-format="Y-m-d" id="edit-changed" name="changed" value="" size="10" class="form-date form-item__element--date form-item__element" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you share the url or screen shot of the date picker have to see

Comment: @akshaypatil added screenshot and snippet

Comment: yes i have seen finding you better solution

Comment: Why do you feel a need to test the actual datepicker itself?  That level of testing is typically done by the datepicker developers themselves in unit testing, not automation testing.

Comment: I was given to automate it. Since datepicker is developed using  attribute type="date". It doesn't have a Dom to it. So I just used send keys to text box

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If you want to check whether DatePicker is present ot not, Pass the locator of the title of the datepicker (ex:month name) and use an if condition

```
// Validate the title, so that you can find whether the date picker is present or not 
If(monthname.isdisPlayed()) {

....
}
```

First find what type of date picker is it.. If it's jquery date picker you can inspect and handle it.

Above calendar is a jquery date picker!

Comment: I don't think mine is a jquery date picker. attached screenshot

Answer (score 0):

So i have done the same date picker operation but the front end is made in angular js  i will share with you the code

[image]

[image]

So what i did is i first click on the input field and after that pass the date using send text in date format i will show you the code..

```
 public static WebElement txtFRegEndDate(WebDriver driver)
    {
        WebElement element = null;
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 50);
        element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@id='FarmerEndDate']")));
        return element;
    }

 WebElement txtFRegEndDate = FrDateSetPage.txtFRegEndDate(driver);
 txtFRegEndDate.clear();
 Thread.sleep(2000);
 txtFRegEndDate.sendKeys(datArr[8].toString());
```

In my case this works for me and also this above code is in java so you can same do this in python let us know if you have any doubts